# redirect sys.stdout to a wx.TextCtrl widget

Tags: python, wxwidgets, wx.textctrl

I'm trying to redirect the sys.stdout stream to a wx.TextCtrl widget. I've managed to get the stream to redirect but apparently some messages get writted twice. Hopefully somebody can explain this to me.

I'm using python 2.7.5 with wx 2.8.12.1, running from IPython 1.1.0.

```
import sys
import wx


class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, 1, title='Example', size=(500, 500))

        console = Console(self)
        sys.stdout = console

    # Restore default stdout stream
    def __del__(self):
        Destroy()

    def Destroy(self):
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__


class Console(wx.TextCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.txtctrl = wx.TextCtrl(parent, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_AUTO_SCROLL | wx.TE_RICH2)

    def write(self, message):        
        self.txtctrl.AppendText('>>> ')
        self.txtctrl.AppendText(message)


def main():
    app = wx.App()

    frame = Example()
    frame.Center()
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Are you sure that the lines aren't written twice without output redirection?

Comment: that's what I thought too but when I run "print('This is a test')" the TextCtrl will display ">>> This is a test>>> "

Comment: Try adding to the beginning of your `write` function: `if not len(message): return`

Comment: perfect, got it sorted now. It seems to be a separate newline character, which I filtered out using `if message == '\n'`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Be aware that wx.Frame inherits "Destroy()" from wx.Window. Your subclass "Example()" which sub-classes wx.Frame overrides the inherited "Destroy()" method.